# Assigning value to nested list element using outer list element name

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I have a nested list, `my_list4`. I want to change the value of the inner most list elements using the `names()` of one of the outer list elements.

Here is `my_list4`;

```
my_list <- list(elem1 = 1:3, elem2 = 4:6, elem3 = 7:9)
my_list2 <- list(elem1_2 = my_list, elem2_2 = my_list, elem3_2 = my_list)
my_list3 <- list(elem1_3 = my_list2, elem2_3 = my_list2, elem3_3 = my_list2)
my_list4 <- list(Species1 = my_list3, Species2 = my_list3, Species3 = my_list3)
```

A nested `lapply` seems like a good start;

```
assign_value <- lapply(my_list4, FUN = function(x){
  lapply(x, FUN = function(y){
    lapply(y, FUN = function(z){
      lapply(z, FUN = function(t){
        t = NA
      })
    })
    
  })
})
```

This changes the inner most elements to the value `NA`. I want to change the values to the species that they correspond to, though (ie. Species1, Species2, Species3), as is described by `names(my_list4)`.

So, `assign_value$Species1$elem1_3$elem1_2$elem1` is `NA`, but I want it to be Species1. `assign_value$Species2$elem1_3$elem1_2$elem1` is `NA` but I want it to be Species2.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a `for` loop to assign

```
assign_value <- my_list4

for(nm in names(my_list4)) {
   for(nm2 in names(my_list4[[nm]])) {
     for(nm3 in names(my_list4[[nm]][[nm2]])) {
     assign_value[[nm]][[nm2]][[nm3]] <- nm
     }
   }
}
```

-checking

```
assign_value$Species1$elem1_3$elem1_2
#[1] "Species1"

assign_value$Species2$elem1_3$elem1_2
#[1] "Species2"
```

Comment: The value of ```t``` needs to be a species (Species1, Species2, Species3). I just used ```NA``` as an example of how a nested ```lapply()``` could be used to change the value of all the innermost list elements. The innermost list elements can be traced back to a certain species. I need the values of the innermost list elements to be the species that they are derived from.

Comment: @nateroe i updated with a for loop.  Please check if that is what you wanted